# Launch System Console, Blender 3.0

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, workspaces, output

Is there a way to launch the system console from inside Blender? I'm running a script that displays info in the console. I don't want the end-user to have to launch Blender from the command line. Best would be if I can launch the console from the script itself. Some command for that?

There is no 'Toggle System Console' option in Blender 3.0 (I'm on Mac OS).

[image]

Comment: The entry is certainly there under Windows in 3.0.1 below the Save Screenshot (Editor) entry.

Answer (score 1):

This option is available only for Windows. In Linux and MacOS, you are going to have to launch blender from terminal.
To do this, open terminal, then type inside:

Linux:

```
blender
```

MacOS:

```
cd /Applications/Blender
./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
```

Blender will be launched with output to terminal.

If you need to do this often, you can make an alias so that typing just blender in the terminal works. For that you can run a command like this in the terminal (with the appropriate path).

```
echo "alias blender=/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you then open a new terminal, the following command will work:

```
blender
```

Comment: I do know about that. I made an add-on for people, I didn't want to tell them to open system console from command line to see logs. But I guess I'd do just that then.

Comment: Sure, if it had been possible, it would have been here